# Simple if then not doing as expected

Tags: shell, sh

Using this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
DBVALUE=$(/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server -UUser -P"Password" -dDatabase -Q"SELECT something from table WHERE this = "that" | grep yes)
echo "$DBVALUE"
if [ "$DBVALUE" != "yes" ]
then
  echo "no"
  exit 0
else
  echo "yes"
fi
```

echo DBVALUE returns "yes"
if-then returns "no"

If I swap out my SQL lookup with DBVALUE="yes" the if-then returns "yes"

Why doesn't the DBVALUE result of "yes" from the SQL lookup return a yes in the if-else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the database result was trailing with a bunch of spaces, so "yes     " did not equal "yes".

I stripped the spaces:
DBV="$(echo "$DBVALUE" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

And it tested successful!

As tripleee pointed out, I can use a flag to remove the spaces:
DBVALUE=$(/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server -UUser -P"Password" -dDatabase -Q"SELECT something from table WHERE this = 'that'" -W | grep yes)

Comment: Probably a better fix is to run the SQL query with an option to disable any decorations. What exactly this means depends on the SQL variant, but look for disabling heades and padding, or an option for machine readable output.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The -W flag took care of it for the sqlcmd tool. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a double quote missing at the end of the sql query. Also, by using unescaped double quotes around "that", the query and everything subsequently in that script might not be executed as expected.

The solution would be to escape the double quotes with a backslash.

```
DBVALUE=$(/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server -UUser -P"Password" -dDatabase -Q"SELECT something from table WHERE this = \"that\"" | grep yes)
```

Comment: This is probably just a typo in the question; if it were actually an issue the rest of the script would be part of the `-Q` option to `sqlcmd` and nothing would actually be executed.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it was a typo in the question: -Q"SELECT something from table WHERE this = 'that'"